# "Setup version for module 'xxx' is not specified"

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.0

I've been trying to get up to speed on how to build Magento 2 modules using the merchant beta but when building a module I'm getting stuck at the error message in the title.

From what I've understood this error message should be showing up if I've forgotten to add `setup_version="x.y.z"` to my `<module>`element in `etc/modules.xml` but I already have that. So, what other "magic" causes of this error exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well duh, just realized that renaming `etc/modules.xml` to `etc/module.xml` fixed it.

I **did** think it was an odd name but saw multiple tutorials on Magento 2 modules call it `modules.xml`

Comment: Hi, I searched the documentation on devdocs and saw no mention of modules.xml (plural). Please let us know if you found otherwise.

Comment: The problem was that I looked an various tutorials online and several of them called the file ``modules.xml`` so I named my file that. Finally I decided to try ``module.xml`` instead and that worked. So just people online who can't be bothered to check that their example code is actually correct.